# How to list nodes posted in current month?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I try to list nodes posted in current month, with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

I tried to add a Contextual filter: `Created: month`, but no node appears.

I tried a Filter criteria: `Content: post date / Is equal to / An offset ... / "-1 month"`, but no node appears.

Do you know how can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a filter criteria **Content: Post date** and select **Is greater than or equal to**, value type **An offset from current time** and value **-1 month**.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]